# How can I play video in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I worked on new website which play videos , these videos i save their path on DB and upload the videos " physical files" on folder in project directory . what i need is the best way which I can play this videos on asp.net . I searched more but i couldn't reach to the best . is there is tool in asp.net support play the video ? also what about JQuery is the best on playing the video ? .

```
<asp:DataList ID="DL_Media" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <iframe width="215" height="160" src='<%#Eval("Media_File")%>' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen
                                runat="server"></iframe>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Detect HTML5 video](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#video) `<video src=""></video>`along with **[Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/)**

```
if (Modernizr.video) {
  // let's play some video!
} else {
  // no native video support available :(
  // maybe check for QuickTime or Flash instead
}
```

In Plain Javascript

```
function supports_video() {
  return !!document.createElement('video').canPlayType;
}
```

If HTML 5 video is not supported by browser, you can inform that not supported or use flash/silverlight player

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to use the video tag:

```
<video src="..."></video>
```

More information here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is the answer to your problem